How to create one list of indices for user prompt (Are you happy with this list? y/n) python
I have a python script where I delete the ElasticSearch indices that have a docs.count of zero. I want to make this tool for secure, where I let the user view the list of indices before deciding to proceed with deletion.
This is because the list may contain elasticsearch service indices, which shouldn't be deleted.
Here is the snipped of script where I attempt to list the indices and ask the user if they are happy to proceed with deletion:
content = json.loads(getRequestElasticSearch.text)

  indices_to_delete = []
  for index in content:
        if int(index['docs.count']) == 0 and not index['index'].startswith("."):
           indices_to_delete.append(index['index'])
           print("Indices to be deleted:")
           for idx in indices_to_delete:
             print(idx)
           proceed = input("Do you want to proceed with the deletion of these indices? (y/n): ")
           if proceed.lower() != "y":
              print("Deletion aborted by user.")
              return

When the script works, but the ouput of the list is not very user friendly. e.g. if there are x amount of indices that fit the if condtion, I will be asked x amount of time if I approve of deleting the indice. I would prefer one big list of indices then ask the user if they are happy to proceed with deletion. How would I do that?

Your code that does the prompt, is inside your loop, so is going to run once for each time through. You need to move it outside the loop, when indices_to_delete will be fully populated

That doesn't work for me, if I bring it outside of the loop.
It just keeps returning the input question, never exiting.
